# How do i find weighted normal vector?

Tags: average

How do I find the weighted average of a normal vector.

Heres a phrase from my book

a weighted average might be used where the weights are
determined by the areas of the polygons (e.g., polygons with larger areas have more weight than polygons with smaller areas).

Answer (score 2):

The average of a vector $[x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n]$ is calculated simply
$$\overline x = \frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots + x_n}{n} = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{n}x_i$$

If you want to calculate a weighted average, take some set of weights $w_1,w_2,\dots,w_n\geq 0$ such that $w_1+\cdots +w_n = 1$ and calculate the weighted average using the formula

$$\overline{x_w} = \sum_{i=1}^n w_i x_i$$

*Notes*:

1. The standard average of a vector, $\overline x$, is actually a "weighted average" if you take all weights equal to $\frac 1n$.
2. If the weights are positive but do not sum to $1$, you can divide them by their sum so they do. Alternatively, you can simply calculate $$\overline{x_w} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i}$$
3. Any number between the minimum and maximum value of $x_i$ can be the weighted average of $x$ if you pick the correct weights.